# Unable to submit ios app to appstore after transfer

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have transferred an ios app to a new account successfully. However when I re-build and upload the app I receive an email to say it can be submitted to the appstore.

However in itunes connect, although the new build appears under TestFlight it does not appear in the main list of builds for the app. Onlt the build uploaded before the transfer appear in the list.
How do I  get it to appear in the main list of builds so that I can submit it to the appstore.

Comment: Is the new build uploaded with higher version than the current one in the App Store. And are you adding new version in the main versions screen?

Comment: itunesconnect -> App Store (tab) -> + Version or Platform (bottom of the left panel)

Comment: The new version has a higher version number (2.6.2) than the appstore (2.4.5).
I have uploaded the new version with Application Loader. The new version appears under the Test Flights.

Comment: itunesconnect -> App Store (tab) -> + Version or Platform (bottom of the left panel)
Only the tvOS option is available iOS is disabled.

Comment: Probably you should try to upload it trough xCode, there maybe you will receive more information?